# Posición 0 en arreglo de formulario javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este formulario. Al enviar la fecha siempre me toma la posición 0 del arreglo.
¿Cómo puedo enviar otra posición del arreglo? he intentado de todo y siempre llega la posición 0 de todo. ¿Cómo realizar dicha labor?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < medir.length; i++) {
  //console.log(contador);
  productContainer.innerHTML += 
    `
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 mt-4" >
  

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#exampleModal${contador}">
          
          ${ingresar.hora_completa10[i]}
        </button>
        <hr size="3px" color="lead" />

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal${contador}" tabindex="-1" 
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel${contador}" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel${contador}">
                Informacion ${ingresar.nom_prestacion[i]}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ${ingresar.hora_completa10[i]}
                ${ingresar.preparacion[i]}
                <form action="../agenda/datos_paciente2.php" method="GET" id="form">
                <div class="auto" id="auto" name ="auto" style="display: none">
                  ${[i]}
                </div>
                  <input type="hidden" name="especialidad" value="${ingresar.especialidad[i]}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="prestacion" value="${ingresar.id_prestacion[i]}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="centro" value="${ingresar.id_facility[i]}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id_medico" value="${ingresar.id[i]}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="form_date" value="${ingresar.fecha_completa[i]}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="hora_completa" value="${ingresar.hora_completa10[i]}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="rut" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="modo" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="ee33e909372d935d190f4fcb2a92d542">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitform(); return false;">
                  Agendar</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        
    
  </div>  
</div> 

`
contador++;
};
```

Comment: no me falta, por espacio no agregue el ciclo for, pero hay se ve que itera [i], los datos llegan en un json, luego se recorre en un ciclo for

Comment: Para estar seguro tendrías que agregar más código... Pero asi por encima, se me ocurre que depronto la funcion `submitform` este usando el formulario con `id=form`... Pero como todos los formularios tienen el mismo id, siempre termina enviándose el primero. El `id` de un elemento en html sebe ser único

Comment: No sé, pero tiene toda la pinta de que deberías hacer `ingresar[i].hora_completa10` y NO `ingresar.hora_completa10[i]` como lo estás haciendo...mismo caso para todos los otros atributos

Comment: gracias por las respuestas 
en el php tenia el form dentro del card donde hacia el innerHTML y por eso me tomaba la posicion 0

Comment: saque el form del card y solucion al problema

Answer (score 2):

```
                <form action="../agenda/datos_paciente2.php" method="GET" id="form">
     <             div class="row" id="card-ingresar">
                      
                    <input type="hidden" name="especialidad" value="<?=$especialidad2;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="prestacion" value="<?=$id_prestacion;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="centro" value="<?=$id_facility;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_medico" value="<?=$id;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_date" value="<?=$fecha_completa;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hora_completa" value="<?=$hora_completa;?>">
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rut" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="modo" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="ee33e909372d935d190f4fcb2a92d542">
                    
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agendar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                  </div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o una edición a tu pregunta? De ser lo primero, pulsa en [edit] para describir lo que hace; de ser lo segundo, borra esta _no-respuesta_.